# Perl equivalent of (Python-) list comprehension

Tags: python, perl, list-comprehension

I'm looking for ways to express this Python snippet in Perl:

```
data = {"A": None, "B": "yes", "C": None}
key_list = [k for k in data if data[k]]  
# in this case the same as filter(lambda k: data[k], data) but let's ignore that
```

So looking at it one way, I just want the keys where the values are *None* or *undef*. Looking at it another way, what I want is the concise perl equivalent of a [list comprehension with conditional](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Do you mean you want to _exclude_ the keys where the values are None or undef?  That's what your example does.

Comment: Hmm. In hindsight that *does* sound quite ambiguous. I guess that by "I want the keys" I referred to "I want them - so that I can filter them out" but the question that got answered was the right one: how to do pick certain stuff out of a collection in a one liner. Sorry :)

Comment: normally i use `map{ f($_)} grep{cond($_)} @list`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you want [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = ( A => undef, B => 'yes', C => undef );

my @keys = grep { defined $data{$_} } keys %data;

print "Key: $_\n" for @keys;
```

I also think that I type too slowly, and that I should reload the page before posting answers. By the way, either a value of `0` or `undef` can be a good way to handle *null* values, but make sure you remember which you're using. A false value and and undefined value aren't the same thing in Perl. To clarify: `undef` returns false in a boolean test, but so does `0`. If `0` is a valid value, then you want to explicitly test for definedness, not simply truth. (I mention it because James went for `0` and I went the other way, and you may or may not know if it matters.)

Comment: It doesn't matter that you type slowly, you get more votes anyway! :)

Comment: Which is odd, since we wrote essentially the same answer. I completely don't get the voting here.

Comment: I think it's a sign that Perl programmers on this site think undef > 0 in this instance. :-P

Comment: Chris has hit the nail on the head here. I've definitely learnt my lesson. :)

Voting is odd. No big deal, and you have good answers anyhow so I don't mind.

Comment: Yeah the two proposed solutions are very similar, but I think the note about undef was helpful, so I'll go with the majority vote. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 13):

Use [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = ("A" => 0, "B" => "yes", "C" => 0 );
my @keys = grep { $data{$_} } keys %data;
```

Grep returns the values from the list on the right-hand side for which the expression in braces evaluates to a true value. As [telemachus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26702/telemachus) points out, you want to make sure you understand true/false values in Perl. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036347/how-do-i-use-boolean-variables-in-perl/) has a good overview of truth in Perl.

You'll likely want a look at [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), which applies an expression in braces to each element of a list and returns the result. An example would be:

```
my @data = ("A" => 0, "B" => 1, "C" => 0 );
my @modified_data = map { $data{$_} + 1 } @data;
print join ' ', @data, "\n";
print join ' ', @modified_data, "\n";
```

Comment: Cool.  I have seldom seen the "non-m//" generalized grep in Perl.  I usually use "map" for stuff like this, with a block like: { <<cond>> ? $_ : () }.  TMTOWTDI, I guess  :-)

Comment: @Roboprog - Thanks. I think this is more concise, but your way is definitely good too.

@ysth - can you give a more concrete example? What's up with the !! characters? It's Perl, so I'm tempted to try it. :)

Comment: @James Thompson: ()x in list context is the list repetition operator.  !!() booleanizes; anything true becomes 1, anything false becomes (in the numeric context provided by ()x) 0.  So grep { xxx } is equivalent to map { ($_)x!!( xxx ) } since the $_ will be repeated 0 times when xxx is false and once when xxx is true.  I was lightly making fun of the idea of using map to do a grep by showing an even sillier way to do it.

Comment: if i understood, `[f(x) | x in list , pred(x)]` can be coded as   `map { f(x) x!! pred(x) } list` cool!!

Answer (score 6):

For variation on the theme have a look at [autobox](http://search.cpan.org/dist/autobox/) (see its implementations  [autobox::Core](http://search.cpan.org/dist/autobox-Core/) and [Moose::Autobox](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose-Autobox/) )

```
use autobox::Core;

my %data = ( A => undef, B => 'yes', C => undef );
my $key_list = %data->keys->grep( sub { defined $data{$_} } );

say "Key: $_" for @$key_list;

# => Key: B
```

Moose::Autobox comes with key/value 'kv' which makes the code DRYer:

```
my $key_list = %data->kv->grep( sub{ defined $_->[1] } )->map( sub{ $_->[0] } );
```

Here is a more explicit and even longer version of above:

```
my $key_list = %data->kv
                    ->grep( sub { my ($k, $v) = @$_; defined $v } )
                    ->map(  sub { my ($k, $v) = @$_; $k }         );
```