# How can I filter items from a list in Python?

Tags: python

I have data naively collected from package dependency lists.

Depends:  foo bar baz >= 5.2

I end up with

```
 d = set(['foo','bar','baz','>=','5.2'])
```

I don't want the numerics and the operands.

In Perl I would

```
@new = grep {/^[a-z]+$/} @old
```

but I can't find a way to e.g. pass remove() a lambda, or something.

The closest I've come is ugly:

```
[ item != None for item in [ re.search("^[a-zA-Z]+$",atom)   for atom in d] ]
```

which gets me a map of which values out of the set I want...*if* the order of the set is repeatable?  I know that's not the case in Perl hashes.

I know how to iterate.  :)   I'm trying to do it the pythonesque Right Way

Comment: Take a look at this post (which is kind of your question in reverse): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112444/perl-equivalent-of-python-list-comprehension/1112462

Comment: OT remark: The idiomatic way to test for None in Python is "is". Use "item is not None" instead of "item != None"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No need for regular expressions here. Use [`str.isalpha`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha).  With and without list comprehensions:

```
my_list = ['foo','bar','baz','>=','5.2']

# With
only_words = [token for token in my_list if token.isalpha()]

# Without
only_words = filter(str.isalpha, my_list)
```

*Personally* I don't think you have to use a list comprehension for everything in Python, but I always get frowny-faced when I suggest `map` or `filter` answers.

Comment: Filter without lambda is A-OK

Comment: Filter without lambda in this (surprisingly common) case is A-OK as long as you're not mixing str and unicode objects, all hell breaks loose otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
d = set([item for item in d if re.match("^[a-zA-Z]+$",item)])
```

that gives you just the values you want, back in d (the order may be different, but that's the price you pay for using sets.

Comment: match() makes the "^" useless: re.match("[a...").

Answer (score 1):

What about using filter function
In this example we are trying to only keep the even numbers in list_1.

```
 list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 filtered_list = filter(lambda x : x%2 == 0, list_1)
 print(list(filtered_list))
```

This prints the new list which contains only the even numbers from list_1

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: oh I used an example but use filter function to filter items