# Removing a white space in a List

Tags: python, list

Im trying to remove a white space in a list.

```
lis = ['H','','w']


print(lis)
```

I expect the output ['H','W']

Comment: There isn't any white space in that list to begin with. Also `replace` is a function on strings, not lists

Comment: Lists don't have a `.replace()` method.  That can't be your actual code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I filter items from a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314314/how-can-i-filter-items-from-a-list-in-python)

Comment: `print(list("".join(lis).replace(' ', '')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

```
lis = ['H','','w']

lis = [item for item in lis if item]
print (lis)
```

or:

```
lis = ['H','','w','']

while '' in lis:
    lis.remove('')
print(lis)
```

output:

['H', 'w']

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by the following list comprehension method.

```
lis = [item for item in lis if item ]
```

Or by the built in function `lis.remove('')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to remove any element that contains whitespace or is blank

```
lis = ['H', '', '', 'W']
temp = []

for element in lis:
    if not (element.isspace() or element==''):
        temp.append(element)

print(temp)
```

Comment: Generally, iterating while removing items is a cause for trouble. For example, try it when `lis` contains more than one space.

Comment: @Tomothy32 It would still work if list would contain more than one space since it iterates through all elements of specified list

Comment: Have you tried it? Removing elements while iterating usually leads to skipped elements.

Comment: Sorry, I meant have you tried it with a list with two or more spaces. For example, try with `lis = ['H', '', '', 'W']`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for editing. :) By the way, it might be easier to use a list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I changed my code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use `.remove()` to remove items.

```
lis.remove('')
```

This will only remove the *first* occurrence of the item, so if the list can have more than one, you'll have to call `.remove()` in a loop, or handle it another way.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using sort:

```
lis = ['H','w', '']

if '' in lis:
    lis.sort(key=lambda k: k=='')
    print(lis[:lis.index('')])
else:
    print(lis)
```

Prints:

```
['H', 'w']
```