# Update nested list in python

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python.

I have a list in python like this :-

```
l = [['0010-CHSUF123','ABC @amp; Co'], ['0020-USD','XYZ @amp; Co']]
```

I am trying to traverse the list and remove @amp from all strings in the list :

```
def updatelist(l):
 for list in l:
   for val in list:
       if isinstance(val,type(str)):
            val = unescape(val)
            print(val)
```

It does update the values but not the list.

Kindly assist

Comment: You are never updating your list so why would you expect it to change?

Comment: @Julien .. yeah thats what i was trying to do, how to update the list. Thanks

Comment: `for i,val in enumerate(list): ... list[i] = new_value`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I filter items from a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314314/how-can-i-filter-items-from-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a list comprehension and the `replace` method:

```
[[i.replace('@amp', '') for i in j] for j in l]
```

Output:

```
[['0010-CHSUF123', 'ABC ; Co'], ['0020-USD', 'XYZ ; Co']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(l)):
    for j in range(0, len(l[i])):
        print(l[i][j])
        if '@amp' in l[i][j]:
            s = l[i][j].split('@amp')
            l[i][j] = s[:]
```