# Is there a built-in true/false boolean value in Perl?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use boolean variables in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036347/how-do-i-use-boolean-variables-in-perl)

```
[root@ ~]$ perl -e 'if(true){print 1}'
1
[root@ ~]$ perl -e 'if(false){print 1}'
1
```

I'm astonished both `true` and `false` passes the `if`...

Comment: take a look at "man perlsyn" or http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html

Comment: Over a decade later, Perl gets true and false "distinguished booleans" through the new [builtin](https://perldoc.perl.org/builtin) package

Answer (score 15):

If you run it with strict:

```
perl -Mstrict -e 'if(true) { print 1 }'
```

you would get the reason:

```
Bareword "true" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at -e line 1.
```

It is interpreted as string `"true"` or `"false"` which is always true. The constants are not defined in Perl, but you can do it yourself:

```
use constant { true => 1, false => 0 };
if(false) { print 1 }
```

Answer (score 10):

You are using barewords `true` and `false`. Bare words are a Bad Thing. If you try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
if (true){print 1}
```

You'll probably get something like this:

```
Bareword "true" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at - line 3.
Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Any defined value that doesn't look like 0 is considered "true". Any undefined value or any value that looks like 0 (such as `0` or `"0"`) is considered "false". There's no built-in keyword for these values. You can just use `0` and `1` (or stick in `use constant { true => 1, false => 0};` if it really bothers you. :)

Comment: I am porting 4GL code to Perl 5, and having the constants helps. I had forgotten about those. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Always use warnings, *especially* on one-liners.

Perl has no true or false named constants, and without warnings or strict enabled, a "bareword" (something that could be a constant or function but isn't) is silently interpreted as a string.  So you are doing `if("true")` and `if("false")`, and all strings other than `""` or `"0"` are true.