# How do i interpret this if statement

Tags: perl

```
if ( $2 && $3 && $3 != 0 )
```

what is the above logic in Perl?  I've never seen an if condition like this in other languages.  $2 and $3 are just capturing groups of some regex.

or this:

```
if ( $2 && $2 == 0 && $3 && $3 == 0 )
```

Comment: can you show you code?

Comment: What other languages do you use? C, C++, Java, JavaScript accept the same expression (with appropriate variables for the language), and I'm sure Python and Ruby do too. The only language I can think of where this doesn't work as in Perl is BASIC and thus probably VB, and even then I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8):

In Perl, a variable evaluates to true if it is defined, non-zero (*see special cases in amon's comment) and non-empty. The final condition is redundant as `$3` can't evaluate to true and be 0.

The code is simply ensuring that capture groups 2 and 3 captured something.

Also see: [How do I use boolean variables in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036347/how-do-i-use-boolean-variables-in-perl)

Comment: In some special cases, the final condition isn't redundant. Consider the strings `"0E0"` and `"0 but true"`, which are both true, despite being zero numerically.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( $2 && $3 && $3 != 0 )
```

Means, if $2 and $3 are successfull captured and $3 is not 0

So `$line = 'a b c 4';`

```
$line =~ m/(\d)\s?(\d)\s?(\d)/;
# $1 is 4, $2 is undef, $3 is undef. Your if statement would fail.
$line2 = '3 4 5 6';
$line2 =~ m/(\d)\s?(\d)\s?(\d)/;
# $1 = 3, $2 = 4, $3 = 5. Your if statement is successfull.
```

`if ( $2 && $2 == 0 && $3 && $3 == 0 )`

Just Means the same, but the 2nd and the 3rd match need to be 0.

`$line = '5 0 0 4';`

```
$line2 =~ m/(\d)\s?(\d)\s?(\d)/;
# $1 = 5, $2 = 0, $3 = 0. Your if statement is successfull.
```

Comment: ITYM 'successfully captured and true'.  Consider `$line3 = '1 0 1 0';`.