# What does "if (1)" do?

Tags: perl

What does the syntax

```
if (1) {}
```

do?

I can't find documentation for this syntax and 1 is not being treated as a boolean. Am I right?.

Comment: Try casting true / false to integers. You'll see that 1 is true, and 0 is false.

Answer (score 20):

Technically, the `if (1)` does nothing interesting, since it's an always-executed if-statement.

One common use of an `if (1)` though is to wrap code you'd like to be able to quickly disable, say for debugging purposes.  You can quickly change an `if (1)` to `if (0)` to disable the code.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, 1 is treated as true, so the block after `if (1)` is always executed.

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html)

> The number 0, the strings '0' and "" , the empty list () , and undef are all false in a boolean context. All other values are true.

Answer (score 4):

`1` is indeed being treated as a boolean value in this case, which always evaluates to `true`.

This is basically an `if` statement which *always* passes (making it unnecessary in the first place).

Answer (score 2):

It runs the code block. It's equivalent to:

```
{
  ...
}
```

---

**Added by ikegami:**

No, it's not.

`{ ... }` is a "bare loop", a loop that executes only once. It is affected by `next`, `last` and `redo`.

`if (1) { ... }` is not a loop. It is not affected by `next`, `last` and `redo`.

```
>perl -E"for (1..3) { say $_; if (1) { next; } say $_; }"
1
2
3

>perl -E"for (1..3) { say $_; { next; } say $_; }"
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

However, they are similar in that both create a lexical scope.

Comment: (Adding a comment in the answer so I can explain the differences in detail.)

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, use `Deparse`:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'if (1) {}'
do {
    ()
};
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 1 **is** being treated as a boolean true by virtue of the fact that the `if` doesn't evaluate to false.  See [How do I use boolean variables in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036347/how-do-i-use-boolean-variables-in-perl)

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, boolean statements are false if they return a value of `0` and true otherwise. A numeric value returns its value.

In that statement, the user is forcing the value of the `if` statement to be true:

```
if (1) {
    print "This statement is always true\n";
}
```

And, of course:

```
if (0) {
    print "This statement is false, and you'll never see this printed\n";
}
```

The user could have written something like this too:

```
if ( 1 == 1 ) {
    print "This statement is always true\n"
}
```

You don't usually see this in an `if` statement. Why bother with an `if` if the condition is always true? However, it's quite common for `while` statements if you need an *infinite loop*:

```
while (1) {
    print "Keep doing this over, and over again\n";
}
```

Usually, there's an escape clause:

```
my $count = 0
while (1) {
    $count = $count + 1;
    print "The Count is now $count\n";
    last if $total > 100;
}
```

The only reason I can think someone would want to do this is some sort of debug checking. That is, most of the time the statement would be false, but if set to true, print out some sort of debug statement:

```
if (0) {    #Change from "0" to "1" to debug
    print "DEBUG: The value of foo = $foo\n";
}
```

However, there are better ways of handling something like this, such as through a constant:

```
use constant {
    DEBUG => 0,
};

if (DEBUG) {
    print "DEBUG: The value of foo = $foo\n";
}
```

Or through a debug subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

In `perl`, the following values are considered `false`

```
0
Empty String
```

Everything else is considered `true`

So, `if (1)` is considered to always be `true`

Comment: There are other false values in Perl, including `0.0`, and `undef`.

Answer (score 0):

`if(1)` is indeed returning true every time, it does nothing except define a scope, similar to a code block