# Do 'T' and 'F' have special meaning in Perl 5.16.3?

Tags: perl

I have some Perl code that's doing something bizarre that I can't figure out. I have two variables defined ahead of this section of code:

```
$latestPatch = '000';
$test_setup{appl}{Rev0_OK} = 'F';  # a hash element
```

Both are defined as strings. If I print out the raw variables (wrapping ' around them), `'int($latestPatch)'` is `'0'` and `'$test_setup{appl}{Rev0_OK}'` is `'F'`. So far, as expected. Now I run the following:

```
$shouldInstall = int($latestPatch) == 0 &&
                 $test_setup{appl}{Rev0_OK} eq 'T';
```

`$shouldInstall` ends up with a null value (false/0 expected)! (printing `'$shouldInstall'` gives ''). Step-by-step debug statements (not shown) indicate that `int($latestPatch) == 0` works OK, giving a 1 (TRUE), but `$test_setup{appl}{Rev0_OK} eq 'T'` is null '' (and thus `$shouldInstall` is ''). If I change the test to `$test_setup{appl}{Rev0_OK} eq 'F'`, it is 1 (TRUE). If I change the test to `$test_setup{appl}{Rev0_OK} ne 'F'`, it is again null. What's going on here? There are no error messages being issued. I do have boolean variables TRUE and FALSE defined (as int 1 and 0).

aTdHvAaNnKcSe

Comment: Re: "I do have boolean variables TRUE and FALSE defined (as int 1 and 0)." Just don't do `... == FALSE` or `... == TRUE`!

Comment: I wasn't comparing against my TRUE and FALSE constants. Just `if ($shouldInstall) {...` I was just commenting that I happened to have those constants, in case they had some bearing on the case here. Perhaps I could have been clearer on that.

Comment: I know you weren't here; I was giving general advice. People who create `TRUE` and `FALSE` constants tend to check against them, which makes no sense when the language's definition differs from the constants as is the case here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `$shouldInstall` ends up with a null value (false/0 expected)! (printing `'$shouldInstall'` gives '').

`$shouldInstall` should end up false, and it does. The empty string is just as false as `0`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655485/589924) explaining what is false.

Most operators return `&PL_sv_no` for false, which is a scalar containing signed integer 0, floating point 0 and the empty string.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump("a" eq "b")'
SV = PVNV(0x9c6d770) at 0x9c6c0f0
  REFCNT = 2147483647
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,IOK,NOK,POK,READONLY,pIOK,pNOK,pPOK)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0x8192558 ""
  CUR = 0
  LEN = 0
```

If you use it a string, it'll be the empty string. If you use it a number, it'll be zero.

```
$ perl -wle'print "".("a" eq "b")'

$ perl -wle'print 0+("a" eq "b")'
0
```

This scalar differs from an empty string in that it doesn't warn when treated as a number.

```
$ perl -wle'print 0+""'
Argument "" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.
0
```

Comment: This is the first time I recall seeing 'true' or 'false' results (including for 'eq' etc. string comparisons) that didn't print out as 1 or 0. It seems odd and inconsistent that I'd get an integer 1 for true and an empty string for false, even if technically they work.

Comment: Re: "This is the first time I recall seeing 'true' or 'false' results [...] that didn't print out as 1 or 0.", What did you try?!?!?! `perl -wle'print "a" eq "b"'`, `perl -wle'print 3 == 4'`, `perl -wle'print !1`, etc

Comment: Re: "and an empty string for false", You don't get an empty string for false. And technically, you get both integer and string one for true.

Answer (score 3):

The results of those comparisons seem fine: (some form of) `true` when the 'T'/'F' values match, (some form of) `false` otherwise.

You seem to be assuming that boolean `false` will evaluate to an integer 0. There's no reason to expect that.

For example:

```
$shouldInstall = undef;
print "'$shouldInstall'\n";

$shouldInstall = (1 == 2);
print "'$shouldInstall'\n";

$shouldInstall = "";
print "'$shouldInstall'\n";

$shouldInstall = (1 == 1);
print "'$shouldInstall'\n";
```

prints:

```
''
''
''
'1'
```

as long as you're testing the variable sensibly:

```
if ($shouldInstall) {
}
```

you'll be fine.

Comment: Interesting. Every time I've dumped 'true' or 'false' results before, including 'eq' results, I've gotten an integer 1 or 0. So seeing an empty string (?) for a result threw me.