# Perl If statement without parameters just plain variable is the EXP

Tags: perl

I just wanted to know what does this code do?

```
my $string_1 = "foo bar";
my $val = 3;

if($string_1) {  


}
```

basically what happen if you just use a variable inside an if statement?

thanks

Comment: You declared `$string_1` but you are checking `$string`. Your check will be `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It checks if the value of the variable is `true`. In Perl, everything is true but the following:

- `0` and the string `'0'`
- `undef`
- `()` (the empty list)
- `''` (an empty string)

This is documented in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood). It also works with any other kind of value. You can also put a string, a function call inside the `if` condition. The behavior is always the same.

Comment: Truth is evaluated in scalar context, so the empty list as such does not exist. `()` in scalar context evaluated to plain old `undef`, which is false. (Similarly an empty array in scalar context is `0`, so false.) There is one other thing that evaluates to false which you missed off your list - objects which overload `bool` to return false.

Comment: True. The explanation for `()` is nice, though it's not in perlsyn. I just rephrased what it says there.

Comment: The explanation in perlsyn is actually pretty bad. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655485/589924)

Answer (score 0):

this will check variable '$string' has not null value

Comment: There is no concept of `null` in Perl

Comment: @Zaid - *"There is no concept of `null` in Perl"*  The ASCII `NUL` or `null` is `0x00` and reference to it is made in the Perl documentation, e.g., [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)'s `a` template is *"A string with arbitrary binary data, will be null padded."*