# Result of grep as a boolean

Tags: perl

I am using the below code. On the right of `and` is a `grep` without a numerical comparison. Does that make sense?

```
if ( scalar( grep { $_ eq $ServerTypeId } keys %ServerTypes ) > 0
    and grep { isRegionOK( $_, $DC ) == 1 } keys %$destinationSummary )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Perhaps a more complete example of what you've tried, what happens when you run it, and what you want to happen instead?

Comment: Never mind .. I got the answer.

Comment: It would be better if your defined 'first' and 'second' parts along with code you tried.  If you have your own answer that's fine, but please provide it.

Comment: Note: your first condition could be simplified to just `exists $ServerTypes{$serverTypeID}`

Comment: See `List::Util::any` for a more efficient (short-circuiting) option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl, like C, doesn't have a boolean type. The language defines certain values as being false, and the rest are true. See [How do I use boolean variables in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655485/589924), [Truth and Falsehood](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood).

In scalar context, `grep` returns a count of matches. 0 is false and all other numbers are true, so treating the result of `grep` as a boolean checks if there were any matches. So yes, `grep` can very well be used as the argument of `and`.

---

Let's do some cleanup.

You have the following:

```
scalar( grep { $_ eq $ServerTypeId } keys %ServerTypes ) > 0
and
grep { isRegionOK( $_, $DC ) == 1 } keys %$destinationSummary
```

Checking if a non-negative number is greater than zero is the same as checking if it's true or false.

```
scalar( grep { $_ eq $ServerTypeId } keys %ServerTypes )
and
grep { isRegionOK( $_, $DC ) == 1 } keys %$destinationSummary )
```

`and` (and `>` before that) evaluates its arguments in scalar context, so no need for `scalar`.

```
grep { $_ eq $ServerTypeId } keys %ServerTypes
and
grep { isRegionOK( $_, $DC ) == 1 } keys %$destinationSummary
```

`isRegionOK` region surely returns a boolean value.

```
grep { $_ eq $ServerTypeId } keys %ServerTypes
and
grep { isRegionOK( $_, $DC ) } keys %$destinationSummary
```

`exists` is far more efficient at checking for the existence of a hash element by key.

```
exists($ServerTypes{$ServerTypeId})
and
grep { isRegionOK( $_, $DC ) } keys %$destinationSummary
```

Comment: Thanks you clarified a lot of things.

Comment: I still have one question though. The isRegionOK returns 0 and 1.But doesn't grep return 1 for both these values ?

Comment: In scalar context, grep returns a count of matches (arguments for which the block returned true).