# What do the // and || operators do in Perl?

Tags: perl

Can someone explain me what does this if is checking and when it is passed?

```
if ( $rate_minimum || 0 ) > ( (4 * $rate_max_min) // 120  ):
```

sorry for not being a perl developer

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html has a nice summary

Comment: That is a syntax error. First off, you are missing an enclosing parenthesis. Second, the line is ended with a colon `:`, which does not belong there. And I guess third, the code is pretty pointless as written, and the main point of it would be to avoid undefined warnings (which it doesn't), which could be handled in a better way than this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`||` is the boolean or operator. It will return `$rate_minimum` if `$rate_minimum` is true, and `0` otherwise. The false values are [primarily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655485/589924) `0`, `''` and `undef`.

`//` is very similar, but *only* tests defined-ness.  ([And is only available since Perl 5.10](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.10.0/pod/perl5100delta.pod#Defined-or_operator)). This means a value of `0` still counts, and so if `$rate_max_min` is zero, it *won't* get replaced with `120`. (Where it would if `||` had been used)

So `$rate_miniumum || 0` will return `$rate_minumum` unless it is either: `0`, an empty string or undefined. In which case the `||` will kick in, and it'll be zero instead.

The second part tests if `$rate_max_min` is *defined* and if it isn't, replace that value with 120. (Which allows it to be zero)

See [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for more detail.

As a related point - you can also do `||=` and `//=` to conditionally assign.

E.g.

```
my $value = undef;
$value //= 42;
print $value,"\n";
# 42 

$value = 0; 
$value //= 42;
print $value,"\n";
# 0

$value = 0;
$value ||=  42;
print $value,"\n";
# 42
```

Edit: As noted by [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene)

> As written, (4 * $rate_min_max) // 120 is useless because the result of * is never undef.

That conditional should *probably* be:

```
4 * ( $rate_min_max // 30 )
```

instead.

e.g.:

```
my $rate_min_max = 0;
print 4 * ( $rate_min_max // 30 ),"\n";
$rate_min_max = undef;
print 4 * ( $rate_min_max // 30 ),"\n";
```

Comment: As written, `(4 * $rate_min_max) // 120` is useless because the result of `*` is never `undef`.

Comment: Good point. Will amend. I assume they were _trying_ to trap a `$rate_min_max` of zero, but failing.

Comment: Maybe they accidentally put an extra `/` in their division?

Comment: That's a possiblity too.

Comment: @RobEarl Then `* 4 / 120` could be simplified to `/ 30`.

Comment: Hey @Sobrique, I just want to point out that defined-or (`//`) was first introduced in perl v5.10 (not 5.12). This is particularly important if one is writing a CPAN module, as 5.10 would have to be specified as the minimum version of perl that can be used for the module. http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.10.0/pod/perl5100delta.pod#Defined-or_operator

Comment: Edited the post. Thought it was 5.12, but I probably skipped 5.10 completely :)

Comment: Yeah, your post is great, but as soon as I saw the "IIRC", I thought I'd speak up as I was just working on one of my modules this week and had to do research on a few of the operators, and which version of perl they were brought to life in :)

Answer (score 1):

Following explanation will help you :

See || is an **OR logical operator** and // is exactly the same as ||, except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its truth. Thus, **EXPR1** // **EXPR2** returns the value of **EXPR1** if it's defined, otherwise, the value of **EXPR2** is returned.