# What is the meaning of the following statement in Perl: num //= 0

Tags: perl

What is the meaning of the following statement in Perl:

```
num //= 0
```

Comment: Don't you mean `$var //= 0;`? `num //= 0;` is an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) lists the Perl operators.

> Logical Defined-Or
>
> Although it has no direct equivalent in C, Perl's // operator is
>   related to its C-style "or". In fact, it's exactly the same as ||,
>   except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its
>   truth.

`//=` is just the assignment version of it.

> Assignment operators work as in C. That is,
>
> ```
> $x += 2;
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> $x = $x + 2;
> ```

So it assigns `0` to `num` unless `num` is already defined.

This is distinct from `||` since there are defined values which aren't true (such as `0` or an empty string).

Answer (score 2):

`$num = $num // 0;`

is now the convenient way of

`$num =`[`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html)`$num ? $num : 0;`

`//` is referred to as **defined-or operator**  that [instead of testing for truth, tests for defined-ness](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/10/set-default-values-with-the-defined-or-operator/).

Unless variable is `undef` or array *empty* `()` (which actually [evaluates to an undefined value in scalar context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036347/how-do-i-use-boolean-variables-in-perl/5655485#5655485)) — it's *defined*.

So `my( $a, $b, $c ) = ( '', '0', 0 )` are all *defined* but **false**.

**Beware** prior to [Perl 5.10](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2009/12/perl-5-10-new-features/) there was no such [assignment](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) like `$pi //= PI`.

Answer (score 0):

**num //= 0**, which is equivalent to

```
num = num // 0;
```

It means that it checks if the left operand is defined or not, if defined it returns the left operand else the right operand.

```
my $num;

$num //= 0;

print $num; # optputs 0

$num = 9;

$num //= 0;

print $num; # outputs 9
```

Comment: It is not equivalent to `num = num || 0;`. `//` and `||` are distinctly different. One tests for truthyness the other for definedness.

Comment: So, I understand that if 'num' is not null take 'num' if null take 0. Right?

Comment: @OsamaMostafa — No. Well. Since Perl doesn't have `null`, that can never happen in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin thanks, corrected the answer.