# What the best practice for Boolean types

Tags: boolean

I recently had to maintain a legacy project, the code was a mess with no coding pattern however one thing caught my attention, in some cases Boolean types were created in three different ways:

```
const bool = true; //conventional
const bool = 1;
const bool = !0;
```

I know that not having a coding pattern is a code-smell but I was wondered are there any benefits in using a practice different from the one commonly used? Any performance gain on some compiler or interpreter? I really was instigated with that. Would you like to know if anyone knows about it?

Comment: What is the commonly used practice? python, bash or C?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark which answer you believe is best, or explain why you feel the currently provided answers are not satisfactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should always use the regular way to define a boolean, which is `true` and `false`** *(like already mentioned by Bathsheba)*.

---

In **JavaScript**, most values lead to truthy values in an if-condition. The exception to this rule are the following values ([source](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)):

- `false`
- `0` (zero)
- `""` (empty string)
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN` (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)

Your example:

```
 const bool = true; // the regular way to define a boolean
 const bool = 1; // a Number, this is truthy in an if-condition, but still, it is just a Number
 const bool = !0; // negates a number -> it actually converts it to a boolean during the negation. So, it is actually the same as bool = false;
```

---

If you are programming in another language, there are not always Booleans around. If there is a boolean in the programming language you are writing, you should definitely be using it.

Some examples:

1. In **Java**, there is the primitive datatype boolean (`true` and `false`) and there is a Boolean wrapper class, which also contains methods for conversion etc. (`Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE`). Other values can not be evaluated in an if-condition.
2. In **Perl**, there are no boolean values. You can however use the number values `0` and `1` for a comparison. It is similar to JavaScript, as it also evaluates most values as truthy, except the following ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1036353/3233827)):

   - `0`
   - `'0'`
   - `undef`
   - `''`  # Empty scalar
   - `()`  # Empty list
   - `('')`

Comment: Upvoted. I can't see anything wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use true and false. Anything else is not as clear.

You write a line of code once. You will read it hundreds of times.

Answer (score 1):

This post relates specifically to C/C++, though is reflective of most languages.

The C++ standard states (§4.7/4):

> If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and
>   the value true is converted to one.

The reason that they are all allowed is simply due to the way that the compiler converts the 'truthy' values into a single bit representation.

They all take up the same amount of space when run through a compiler. The reason for the convention is simply for readability - for this reason, not all 'compiler-valid' representations should be considered equally preferable. As mentioned in [Google's C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html):

> Optimize for the reader, not the writer
>
> Our codebase (and most
>   individual components submitted to it) is expected to continue for
>   quite some time. As a result, more time will be spent reading most of
>   our code than writing it. We explicitly choose to optimize for the
>   experience of our average software engineer reading, maintaining, and
>   debugging code in our codebase rather than ease when writing said
>   code.

In short, readability is everything.

Comment: Upvoted. I can't see anything wrong with this answer.